# How to link 2 sheets, so when a cell on sheet1 is modified, sheet2 got updated automatically and viceversa

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to have the same updated values in two differents sheets of google spreadsheet.

So when I edit sheet1, the the values in sheet2 got updated. Also the opposite: when I edit something in sheet2, values in sheet 1 updates automatically.

My belief was that it's not possible because is a circular reference, but actually I found an [answer on Stack Overflow solving it by coding with VBA of Microsoft Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298874/link-two-cells-so-that-edits-to-either-are-reflected), so maybe it would be possible to do something similar by coding with Apps Scripts of Google Sheets. Unfortunately it requires coding on Apps Script, and I'm not a programmer.

So I wonder if that's possible without coding:

My best solution so far is using this formula (on `Sheet2`):

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!$A$3:$BK$1003,"SELECT * WHERE AZ = 1 or BA = 1 or BB = 1",1)
```

Using it, data of sheet1 is shown in sheet 2, but I cannot edit  sheet2. I mean: it's only to view, not to edit as I'd like.

I do not know about coding... So I am looking for a solution without coding. Is that possible?

Comment: Two-way sync is against the operating principle of most spreadsheet software. See [The Spreadsheet Value Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet#Values). You can do it with an `onEdit(e)` script, but there are usually much better ways to achieve underlying real-world goals. Make sure you are not asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676).

Comment: You hit the nail on the head @doubleunary. We made it with "Filter views" by adding the OR formula to a column, and filtering by that column.